# Dynamic Key Name in Dust.js

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I'm looking for a way to call a dynamic key in my dust template file, something like

```
<table> 
{#array1}
<tr>
    {#array2}
    <td>{#array1}{object.#dynAttrName#}{/array1}</td>
    {/array2}

{/array1}
</table>
```

I would like to access to something like "object.attribute1" where 1 is the id of the current object in {array1}. (array1[n].id)

Thank you for your Help !

Comment: This is very similar to another [Dust question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462903/indirection-in-dust-js/14465766#14465766). Sadly, the answer seems to be that this is not currently possible in Dust.

Comment: Thank you I didn't see this one. Too sad we can't do that, I'll try to find another way

Comment: I would follow the Github repo, as this feature may be coming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by adding a helper function to the context object:

**Context object:**

```
{
   get: function (chunk, context, bodies, params) {
       var obj = dust.helpers.tap(params.ofObj, chunk, context);
       var prop = dust.helpers.tap(params.prop, chunk, context);
       return chunk.write(obj[prop]);
   },

   a: {
       b: "bbb"
   }
}
```

**Template**

```
{#get prop="b" ofObj=a/}
```

You can try this in [linkedin dust tester](http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/test/test.html)

I believe it can also be done defining a global dust helper.

Comment: Such a common use-case, I had to do the same thing. I'm surprised/disappointed that dust doesn't have this as a built-in helper or built-in syntax.  Imagine all of the hours wasted from all the different people expecting such simple/fundamental js feature.