# How get value from variable by its name, getting from another variable in Dust.js

Tags: javascript, dust.js

In JS I can do this:

```js
var a = 'name';
var obj = { name: 1 };
alert(obj[a]);
```

How can I get this in Dust.js? I create example, but it's broken. Please, help me fix if.

[Real case](http://jsbin.com/niduruhuge/edit?html,output) for it, is render array of objects with dynamic columns.

```js
var tpl = `{#person row=.}
             {#columns}
               {row[{.}]}
               {@sep}, {/sep}
             {/columns}<br/>
           {/person}`;

var data = {
  "columns": ["id", "name", "age"],

  "person": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Larry",
    "age": 45
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Mike",
    "age": 23
  }]
};

var compiled = dust.compile(tpl, "intro");
dust.loadSource(compiled);
dust.render("intro", data, function(err, out) {
  document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = out;
});
```

```html
<script src="http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/dist/dust-full-0.3.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Key Name in Dust.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505834/dynamic-key-name-in-dust-js)

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks